# Why does x++ behave strangely under Defer?

Tags: bugs, evaluation

**Bug introduced in 10.4.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.1.0 or later**

---

Using `x++` or `x=x+1` inside `Defer` generates strange results.

Evaluating the following commands **one by one** (in three different input cells), with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, one gets:

```
x=1;
```

```
Defer[x++];
```

```
x
(* 15 but I have also seen 17! *)
```

Even stranger, if one creates a notebook with only those same commands, restarts the kernel, and does `Evaluation ► Evaluate Notebook` then the command `x` returns `1` instead of `15`.

Any explanations?

Comment: I get `1` everytime, as I would expect...

Comment: Same for me, `1` everytime.

Comment: First check: [turn off the Suggestions Bar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/121) and try again.

Comment: @user6014 - I forgot to mention that the three commands must be in different cells. (How could I show that in my post?) If they are in the same cell you indeed get 1 every time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Turning off the Suggestions Bar fixes the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @FernandoSaldanha Just say that they must be in different cells. I edited the post to make them appear in 3 code blocks (see the markdown source to learn how).  Please report this bug to Wolfram Support.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What do we do with questions like this?  Close it as a duplicate of what you linked?  Close it as a duplicate of another question about a Suggestion Bar bug?  Post an answer?  I'm really disturbed by the amount of problems the Suggestion Bar causes.  I think it says more about how difficult it is to manipulate *code* in Mathematica than about WRI quality control.  I would never have dared to attempt to implement something like this myself—the risk of evaluation leaks is much too great.

Comment: @Szabolcs - I reported the bug.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a bug. The documentation is a bit less detailed than might be desired, but `Defer` does not strike me as a bullet-proof way to prevent any and all internal evaluation.